# ffmpeg mpeg2 to MP4 H264 produces horizontal lines artifacts in motion scenes

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, ghost-image

My video input is mpeg2 video file as follows:

```
Video: MPEG2 Video 720x576 (4:3) 25fps [V: mpeg2 main, yuv420p, 720x576]
Audio: MPEG Audio 48000Hz stereo 224kbps [A: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, 224 kb/s]
```

Then I use:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.mpg -b:v 3000k -preset superfast out.mp4
```

To get MP4:

```
Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 720x576 (4:3) 25fps 2967kbps [V: h264 high L3.0, yuv420p, 720x576, 2967 kb/s]
Audio: AAC 48000Hz stereo 128kbps [A: SoundHandler (aac lc, 48000 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s)]
```

Everything is good, except I get something like this in motion scenes:

[image]

In the actual source, there is no such thing. In the source, there is no intermediate frames or ghosting - just "discrete" steps.

I tried other presets, as well as other codec like libxvid, but all produced the same result.

So, how should I fix it? Which parameters should I add or which settings to adjust?

Comment: Can you provide a short sample input file containing an action scene? You can create it using something like: `ffmpeg -ss 600 -i input -c copy -t 5 output.mpg`

Comment: Try increasing bitrate. Though it is more common to encode with the crf option to get constant quality.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your input source in interlaced. Your best bet is to deinterlace with an ffmpeg filter such as `-vf yadif=1`. See [yadif documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif) for more info.

Comment: Note that yadif=1 should only be used when there is effectively 1 field per frame, otherwise you'll end up with dup frames. If that's the case, using ```-vf yadif``` will be more efficient.

Comment: Ely, I think you are mistaken about yadif=1 . Yadif =1 will treat each field as a frame. . 2 Fields per frame will cause a doubling of the frame rate, thereby preserving the interlaced resolution, as temporal resolution. Most any other option for deinterlacing will cause a loss of resolution.